# How to clone an input device (microphone) in linux

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

My problem is rather simple. What I wanna accomplish is to simply clone my microphone device.

Now why I wanna do that? Because I have a BOYA NKF-M2 and I wanna split left and right sound into two different channels so that my sound and another person's sound would be in different channels.

I wanted to clone my microphone to choose one of them to only record left sound and another to only record right sound.

I hope I could explain it